# Iterate over constraints in Clang static Analyzer

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang-static-analyzer

I am developing a Clang static analyzer. In this analyzer, I need to iterate over the constraints in a `RangedConstraintManager`, but it seems this class is not public and I can't call its methods nor access its variables.

Is there any way to bypass this problem?

My current solution is to print the constraints using `printJson` method of `ConstraintManager` class and use its output to implement the logic of my analyzer in a program separated from Clang source code. However, it will be much better if I can implement the analyzer in Clang source code itself. (e.g. to later contribute to LLVM project)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use getConstraintMap(ProgramStateRef State) to get a Constraint Map with key SymbolRef and value RangeSet. So you could try iterate this map.